# ListView animation not scaling correctly

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to apply a scaling animation to my list. The idea is that the list collapses to the top, the way I'm doing it is by scaling the Y-axis to nothing. The animation is not being applied correctly however - the list just disappears for the duration listed in the XML file with no interpolation animation, then reappears when the duration has finished. This happens regardless of what fillAfter is set to (which should be true, right?).

Why is this not interpolating correctly, and why it is reappearing again after the animation terminates?

The anim file:

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:duration="500"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        />
</set>
```

How I call the animation:

```java
ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
Animation collapseList = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.collapse_search_results);
list.startAnimation(collapseList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed this by adding pivotX, fromXScale and toXScale values to my XML file. I needed them even though I'm not scaling along the X-axis.

The animation still does not persist however, but I wanted to get rid of the fragment hosting the ListView anyway so I just added a listener to destroy the fragment when the animation has finished.

My working XML file:

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        />
</set>
```